# «Плато» в экономическом значении

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, заимствования, переводы

Перевод «plateau» из Кембриджского англо-русского словаря:

> plateau - LAND, a large area of high, flat land
>
> плато - LEVEL, a period when the level of something stays the same
> отсутствие роста, стабилизация
>
> Sales are still good but they've reached a plateau.

Перевод предложения:

> As commodity prices find their new plateau, both government hope to
> avoid facing new crises.

на русский

> Поскольку цены на сырье находят свое новое плато, власти обеих стран
> надеются избежать новых кризисов.

наверное, неправильный?

Может быть, надо так:

> Поскольку цены на сырье стабилизируются, власти обеих стран надеются
> избежать новых кризисов?

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, что в серьёзную экономическую терминологию это слово не вошло, и это объяснимо: у носителей русского языка со школьным образованием оно прочно ассоциируется с пространственным (геодезическим) аспектом - так именовалось место дуэли Печорина с Грушницким. Оно нашло, правда, некоторое применение в спортивной медицине при оценке по графикам реакции спортсмена на приём препаратов:

https://www.cfin.ru/management/practice/plateau_effect.shtml

В рассматриваемом переводе можно говорить о новом *периоде стабилизации* (или новом *устойчивом уровне*, что практически то же самое) цен.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, для популярной статьи подобное вполне приемлемо, даже образно звучит: "Цены вышли (поднялись, опустились) на новое плато". Но, конечно, не *нашли* и не *свое*.